# Fadeout div when day "x" is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jquery script to fadout a div when day "x" is reached (should global works)?

I dont want a timer like "setTimeout" aso.

**Update:**

For example, I want that the div with the date "12.03.15" automatic fadout if the 13.03.15 is reached.

Comment: What do you mean by "day X"? `setTimeout` is just OK, don't be afraid to use it

Comment: The limit of `setTimeout` is that it's session dependent.  If the OP is after a common fadeout date/time, `setTimeout` is probably not the way to go.

Comment: I'm quite frightened, what happens on this *Day X*?

Comment: Nothing at the moment ;)

Comment: hahaha. day x page which has a js countdown. and you have to be one the page at exactly 00:00. to see the fade animaton

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date object, this way you can set the day in numerous ways, and if said day has arrived you can remove the div.

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();  //returns the day of the month

var dayToRemove = 'x';

if(dayToRemove == day) {
    $(div).fadeOut();
}
```

You could also easily change this to fadeout after a given date.

Comment: This will give the user's computer time.